# Print Columns on separate Section Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Is this Possible in Crystal Reports 11?

This is the Data Set

```
Id   Date   Address    Name
Id1  Date1  Address1   Name1   
Id2  Date2  Address2   Name2
```

I did a group by on Id.

The report prints

```
 Date1  Address1   Name1
 Date2  Address2   Name2
```

I want to print columns in different detail sections.

```
              Date1       
              Date2
```

In a different sections

```
Address1
Address2
```

and so on.
 I need a way to prevent rows from printing together. Instead of rows, Printing one column at a time. Start printing the second column after first one has finished printing.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use sub reports in different detail sections like

sub report in detail section a in this place only date

sub report in detail section b in this place only address

and so on